# Using mean value theorem for functionals.

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations

I am not sure if the use of mean value theorem for functionals is appropriate in this case but I have an intuition that it might work, although I am not sure.

The problem is as follows: Consider an implicit function $F(x,y,f)=0$, where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuous. I have that $\forall f\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, $x=y$ is never a solution to $F$. Also, there exists at least some $f$ for which $x>y$ is a solution to $F$. Can I use some version of the mean value theorem for functionals to show that $x<y$ can never be a solution to $F$, $\forall f\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Why should you able to say such a thing? What if $F$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, that is, $F(x,y,f)=F(y,x,f)$?

Comment: So, $F$ has domain $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$? To use mean value theorem, one need (as my knowledge go) a normed vector space structure. I know that Bourbaki proved a hypergeneralized version, but I have never read it.

Comment: If instead I restrict $f$ inside $F$ to be parameterized by $t$, with $f$ continuous. If we still have that $x=y$ is never a solution $\forall t$ and $\forall f$. Moreover, I can show that $F$ always has a solution. Would it be kosher to claim that $x<y$ can never be a solution since it would imply that there must be some $t$ for which $x=y$ is a solution, which is impossible.